# installation pip install dbt-postgres

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, dbt

I guess just installed **dbt-postgres** according to the article https://docs.getdbt.com/dbt-cli/install/pip
using command **pip install dbt-postgres**
after the installation I have everywhere Requirements already satisfied
[image]

When I try the command to see the version I have an error
''dbt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'
**Does this mean that I didn't downloaded this?**
How to check the version?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` is saying that you already have `dbt-postgres` installed ("Requirement already satisfied") in your local Python 3.10 environment.

Windows is complaining because that Python's site-packages directory is not on your PATH. This is typical; depending on how you install Python on Windows, it is not automatically added to your PATH. (PATH is an environment variable that tells your shell where to search for the commands you type in -- each command is the name of an executable file in a folder somewhere, and PATH is a list of folders to search in for those executable files).

There are a few ways to add Python to your PATH -- see the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) on this subject. If you're new to all of this, your best bet might be to uninstall and re-install Python. The [Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/python-39/9p7qfqmjrfp7?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) is now the best way to do this.

**HOWEVER** there is another issue here too -- you're trying to run dbt on Python 3.10, but currently dbt only supports older versions of Python (3.7-3.9). So when you re-install Python, you're going to want to specify 3.9 (which I linked to above).

Managing multiple versions of Python on your machine can be a real pain, especially on Windows. If you have someone more experienced in your organization (like an engineer who knows Python well), it's well worth your time to get someone to pair with you on this while you work it out.